# find if a python library version satisfies the requirement in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

I intend to write a function that verifies a python library version satisfies a requirement specified by the requirements.txt file. The function header is as follows

```py
def is_satisfied(name: str, version: str, requirement: str) -> bool:
```

some test cases:

```py
assert not is_satisfied("pandas", "1.2.0", "sklearn")
assert is_satisfied("pandas", "1.2.0", "pandas")
assert is_satisfied("pandas", "1.2.0", "pandas>=1,<2")
assert not is_satisfied("pandas", "1.2.0", "pandas>2")
assert not is_satisfied("pandas", "1.2.0", "pandas==1.2.1")
```

I don't want to make this function very complicated, it is better to reuse the pip library as much as possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why?  If this is installed with `pip`, then `pip` has already done this.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? And what would happen in your code if someone's `requirements.txt` specified both `pandas` and `sklearn`?

Comment: You can use the `packaging` library, which is used by pip for version parsing

Comment: The reason of doing this is I have a remote environment which provides two methods `list-packages` and `update-environment`, the `list-packages` method return the result of `pip list` of this remote environment. If I found the list of libraries and versions doesn't match the given requirements.txt file, I will call the `update-environment` method with the given requirements.txt file. Otherwise, do nothing. The `requirement` argument only takes one line of `requirements.txt` file. Iterating the `requirements.txt` is straightforward.

Comment: This is one step of my CI/CD pipeline, calling `update-environment` method will interrupt our product deployment, so I only want to call it when it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this implementation should work

```py
from packaging.requirements import Requirement

def is_satisfied(name: str, version: str, requirement: str):
    req = Requirement(requirement)
    return name == req.name and req.specifier.contains(version)
```